# Rotating an isosceles triangle given a certain direction in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

I'm trying to rotate an isosceles triangle given a certain direction in OpenGL (All this in 2D). For example, if the triangle is  moving up, then the triangle must be pointing up, and this has to be applicated in all the directions(down-right side-left side-up right...etc) in the plane.

The question is, how this can be done? I have the dots (x,y) for the translation and the direction that is an angle(not radian). The code is the following.

```
void Graphics::draw(){
double P[2];
double Direction;

for (int i = 0; i < numBirds; i++)
{
    P[0]      = flock[i]->Px;
    P[1]      = flock[i]->Py;
    Direction = flock[i]->Dir - 90;


    glPushMatrix();
        glColor3d(1, 1, 1);
        //Operacion para el triangulo
        glTranslated(P[0], P[1], 0.0);
        glRotated(Direction, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        /*
            Se mantienen estas proporciones:
            Base: 1
                Altura: 1.9364916731
                Lado (isosceles): 2
        */
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // Inicio del dibujo
        glVertex3d(-1.5, 0, 0); // Primer vertice
        glVertex3d( 1.5, 0, 0); // Segundo vertice
        glVertex3d( 0, 7.9364916731, 0); // Tercer vertice
        glEnd(); // Fin del dibujo

        // Deshago las operaciones de rotacion y translacion
        glRotated(-Direction, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslated(-P[0], -P[1], 0.0);
    glPopMatrix();

    //cout << "Velocidad pajaro "<< i <<" Graph x: "<<flock[i]->Vx << " Velocidad pajaro Graph Y:"<< flock[i]->Vy<<endl;
    //flock[i]->Py 

    physics.updatePosition(flock, flock[i]);

    //cout << "Velocidad update pajaro "<< i <<" Graph x: "<<flock[i]->Vx << " Velocidad pajaro Graph Y:"<< flock[i]->Vy<<endl;
}
```

}

In this version of the code, the triangles are moving in a certain direction(x,y), but the triangle is not pointing(isosceles triangles can point with one vertex) to/toward(?) that dir
ection.

Comment: Can you please specify what happens when you try your version of the code? What exactly is the problem you can't solve?

Comment: The triangles are moving in a certain direction, but they are not pointing (isosceles triangle can point) to that direction.